# Django multiple related forms data processing error

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to make an **app.Model.py**

```
class serviceinvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='invoice')    
    invoice_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = increment_invoice_number, null = True, blank = True)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_receivable=models.ForeignKey(Receivables,null=True)
    total_amount=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    total_amountwithtax=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number

class serviceinvoiceitems(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='serviceinvoiceitems')
    invoice_number=models.ForeignKey(serviceinvoice)
    Product=models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    UOM=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Quantity=models.FloatField(null=True)
    Rate=models.FloatField(null=True)
    Tax_rate=models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class createinvoiceform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=serviceinvoice
        exclude=('user',)
        widgets = {
            'invoice_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }

class invoiceitemform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=serviceinvoiceitems
        exclude=('user','invoice_number',)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def createinvoice(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inv_form=createinvoiceform(data=request.POST)
        inv_item=invoiceitemform(data=request.POST)
        if inv_form.is_valid() and inv_item.is_valid():
            new_form=inv_form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user=request.user
            new_form.save()
            new_invitem=inv_item.save(commit=False)
            new_invitem.user=request.user
            new_invitem.invoice_number=request.invoice_number
            new_invitem.save()
            return HttpResponse('Invoice created')
    else:
        inv_form=createinvoiceform()
        inv_item=invoiceitemform()
        inv_form.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset=Receivables.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/createinvoice.html',{'inv_form':inv_form,'inv_item':inv_item})
```

Forms are displayed in template but are not processed by view.

Getting error,

> (1048, "Column 'invoice_number_id' cannot be null").

Please guide on:

1. How can i process this form, since second form will use foreign key of first form.
2. Is there a way in template to show second form multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Make invoice number as non mandatory field

**models.py**

```
invoice_number=models.ForeignKey(serviceinvoice, null=True, blank=True,
                                 default=None)
```

Comment: But invoice_number is required. Its a foreign key between 2 models.